# Remove special characters like tab (\t) and new line (\n) from a fixed length file

Tags: performance, shell

I have a fixed length file , I need to replace special characters \t from the file.

```
col1 col2 col3 col4    col5
```

This has tab character after `col4`. I need this to be removed, and i am using this command

```
tr -d \011 < file.txt > temp.txt
```

But when i run it all the spaces are removed and i get

```
col1col2col3col4col5
```

And for `\n`, I use `sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' file.txt`, but all the lines are coming into a single line

I need that for the first row col5 should come in the same row,

```
col1col2col3col4 
col5
col1col2col3col4col5
```

When i run the command I get the output as

```
col1col2col3col4col5col1col2col3col4col5
```

Can you please help me in this?

Comment: Have you look towards `colrm` and `paste`? Those are specifically for columns / lines removal operations.

Comment: copy a couple of lines from your input as an example, and also provide expected output.

Comment: Input for \t (octal character 011)

Comment: 0064208520010012009070199991231459 GRACE AVE PANAMA CITY FL324012756 BAY 8502156007 CREDENTIALING@FLATHERAPY.COM NYpanama c001 I0 0 1 17530101 U After CREDENTIALING@FLATHERAPY.COM there is an extra tab character , the final length is 375 , I want the after tab is removed the final length should come at 374 – Neha Singh 42 secs ago   edit   
After using tr command the length 373 extra character is removed

After using tr command the length 373 extra character is removed

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for remove \t

```
cat temp.txt | tr -d '\t' > temp1.txt

cat temp.txt
col1 col2 col3 col4     col5

cat temp1.txt
col1 col2 col3 col4col5
```

Comment: 0064208520010012009070199991231459 GRACE AVE                           PANAMA CITY        FL324012756  BAY                     8502156007                                      CREDENTIALING@FLATHERAPY.COM          NYpanama c001    I0         0            1    17530101                                                                                                        U
After CREDENTIALING@FLATHERAPY.COM there is an extra tab character , the final length is 375 , I want the after tab is removed the final length  should come at 374

Comment: After using tr command the length 373 extra character is removed